# How can I customize or edit OpenLayers.js?

Tags: javascript, geometry, openlayers, kml

How can I customize or edit OpenLayers.js? How can I modify codes, which are created by Openlayers?

For example, I wrote a div tag with an id in my code:

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

In adition, I'm using a kml file for showing some points into my map. So, these codes were added by Openlayers js files into my div:

```
<div id="map" class="olMap">
    <div id="OpenLayers.Map_2_OpenLayers_ViewPort" ...>
        <div id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_26" ...>
            <g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_26_root" style="visibility: visible;" transform="">
                <g id="OpenLayers.Layer.Vector_26_vroot">
                    <circle id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_40" cx="457.56130690092687" cy="33.45180640075705" r="5" style="" fill="#669933" fill-opacity="0.8" stroke="#aaee77" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></circle>
                </g>
            </g>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But, I want to modify those codes. I want to add a link tag before each circle tag. For instance:

```
<a href="#" class="something">
    <circle ...></circle>
</a>
```

What should I do?

---

I used Wrap function of jquery to add tag a. But it doesn't work.
I used this code for adding a tag to circles tag:

```
function warpToCircle() {
    $('circle').wrap('<a href="defualt.aspx" class="b1"/>');
}
```

And it works very well, the reslt code is:

```
<a href="Rod_Wells/Rod_Wells.aspx" class="b1">
    <circle ...>
    </circle>
</a>
```

But, after adding the a tag circle tag is disappeared, and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is relevant to your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/clicking-on-a-polygon-opening-a-page-link

Specifically note the answer not selected as the accepted answer.